# How to move textfield up when keyboard appears

Tags: html

In my website textfield not focusing up when default android keyboard comes. It hides the textbox. any simple solution for that issue.

Comment: @ Arvind thx for your reply. you mean to set autofocus attribute to every textbox in my page?

Comment: @ Aravind please check my question. its the issue with the android key board. iam not trying to focus a particular textbox. when clicking on textbox keyboard hides. it needs to show up

Comment: please check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/fyom081o/

Comment: @ Shinoy Shaji thx for you answer.if the page contain 25 or above text fields then? my problem only appears in touch devices.

Comment: Can you share the code?

Comment: @ Shinoy Shaji sorry. its a large solution.actually the solution is running in a iframe master page concept. any problem with the master page concept any gues iam stuck with this

Answer (score 1):

there will be position:fixed property (in a div related to the text field) ,which prevents the text field from jumping up ...just disable the position property ... i had the same problem

Comment: thx for your answer. yes there is a position fixed property applied to the cover div. may be that is the issue any way thanks. i will test with this case and will send you a feed back. and one more question  if i applied position absulute insted of that any problem occures?

Comment: yea  , but don't forget to check whether this position absolute is effecting other elements or not

Comment: @ Hussainfaizal Salman Fariz.  yup. in primary testing its working fine. In my case position relative is enough. detaild testing is going on. Any why that was a great solution. keep going. after detaild testing i will send you a feed back

Answer (score 0):

this is a basic code to scroll page up and down when virtual keyboard appears

## [JsFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/7tzefemz/1/)

---

**jQuery**

```
var keyboardHeight = 150;

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("textarea, input").focusin(function() {
        var element = $(this);
        var viewportHeight = $(window).height();
        var windowScrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        var offsetTop = element.offset().top - windowScrollTop;
        var validOffset = viewportHeight - keyboardHeight;

        $("#keyboard").fadeIn();

        if(offsetTop <= 0) {
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: windowScrollTop + offsetTop
            }, 1000);
        }
        else {
          if(viewportHeight > keyboardHeight) {
            if(offsetTop > validOffset) {
              $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: windowScrollTop + offsetTop
              }, 1000);
            }
          }
        }
    });

    $("textarea, input").focusout(function() {
        $("#keyboard").fadeOut();
    });
});
```

---

**html**

```
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>

<textarea rows="11"></textarea>

<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>

<div id="keyboard"></div>
```

---

**css**

```
body {
  background: transparent;
  padding-bottom: 150px; /* height of virtual keyboard */
}

textarea {
  width: 100%;
  background: transparent;
  border: solid 1px red;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: white;
  outline: none;
}

#keyboard {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(13, 13, 13, 0.5);
  display: none;
}
```